# Including modules using grails resource plugin, will it duplicate js files when included in template and in main page?

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I have a gsp page with following things at the top of it. My main page name is "mobStep.gsp".

```
<meta name='layout' content='mainNew' />
<r:require module="Step2"/>
```

The Step2 module contains the following modules included like below:

```
Step2 {
    dependsOn "common"
    resource url:"/js/time.js"
}
```

In mainNew layout I have included following statement at top:

```
<r:require module="common" />
```

I have a bunch of js files only (not any css, though that doesn't matter of course) included in common module.

My concern is that by defining js modules this way, it will create duplicates (duplicates of the common module's js files) in my main page mobStep.gsp? When I tried it, duplication wasn't occurring.